# Send image to server - Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type): "Unsupported media type \"image/png\" in request."

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, put

I'm trying to send an image from frontend using ajax to backend using django rest framework without result.

The response error is: `{"detail":"Unsupported media type \"image/png\" in request."}` where instead of "image/png" I tried a lot o different types. (the img I'm sending is a png)

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="" id="profilepic" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*">
<label id="uploadBtn" for="profilepic">Choose your profile photo</label>
```

---

JS:

Note that first I was sending all the nested data as JSON but later I splitted to send the img separeted.

```
var my_data = { "user_url": user_url, "user": username, "atoms": [atom_dict] };
$.ajax({
    url: origin + '/boonds_api' + userurl,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(my_data),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(my_data);
    }
});
// Until here everything is fine sebding data to backend
// Only img
my_img = $('#profilepic')[0].files[0]
var my_data = {"atoms": {"img":my_img}};
$.ajax({
    url: origin + '/boonds_api' + userurl,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "image/png",
    data: JSON.stringify(my_data),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(my_data);
    }
});
```

---

DJANGO

models.py

```
class Atom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='users_app')
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="atoms")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

views.py

```
class UserAccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserAccount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAccountSerializer
    lookup_field = "user_url"
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # update = PUT
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

serializers.py

I tried also different solutions to accept the image but not sure if the error is here, in models or in ajax.

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer # Enable write nested
from .models import *
from drf_base64.fields import Base64ImageField

class AtomSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    boonds = BoondSerializer(many=True,required=False)
    img = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Atom
        fields = ["name","bio", "img", "boonds"]
```

Comment: Did you get any solutions to this?

Comment: @UcheOzoemena I added an answer to this post :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it avoiding using drf (serializer) and just creating a new ednpoint with an update view (UpdateView):

```
class yourImageView(UpdateView):
    model = YourModel
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        img = self.request.FILES["my_img"]
        YourModel.img = img
        YourModel.save()
```

Ajax:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('my_img', my_img);
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: origin + '/new_endpoint/' + userdata.user_id + "/",
     data: form,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
     })
```